# Oracle error in Windows Service after running for a day

Tags: c#, oracle, windows-services

I have a C# Windows Service that calls an Oracle Stored Procedure several times a minute.  It works fine for about 28 hours and then I start getting numeric conversion errors on EVERY ATTEMPT to call the stored procedure.  When I restart the service, the error goes away but I am still inserting the exact same data.  After a little more than a day the error returns.

I have written the data to a log and then I manually call the stored procedure with that same data and there is no error.

I think the error is happening on the call to the proc, not on the actual insert inside the proc.  How can I be sure?

How can I see what is really being sent from the Windows Service to Oracle?

Any troubleshooting tips?

Here is my error – but I don’t think this is the real problem:
Message: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
ORA-06512: at line 1

Comment: whats the procedure code?  Any conversions (implicit or explicit) being done?

Comment: Does it consistently break at the 28 hour point? Is it a little less than 28 hours? Complete shot in the dark here, but 27h 46m 40s = 100,000 seconds.

Comment: The time is not the same each time.  I have seen it happen in less than 10 hours.  28 hours is the longest I have noticed it going.